# Show only a particular category with its sub-categories in Drop-down boxes?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, dropdownbox

This is my first question here.
Drop-down boxes will show a particular category. The script that I have shows the all the categories and all the sub-categories.
Suppose I have a category named 'DEMO' and that category got 3 sub-categories named 'DEMO SC1' , 'DEMO SC2' ,'DEMO SC3'

So I want the dropdown so show DEMO (catagory) and under it
'DEMO SC1' , 'DEMO SC2' ,'DEMO SC3'.
I have this but it shows all catagories and its sub catagories.

```
    <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
<div>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=1&hierarchical=1'); ?>
</div>
```

Thanks for helping me :)

---

Okay , I  used custom post types & taxonomies . I have a simple thing to ask more that is how to include custom post types & taxonomies to search. My taxonomies include things like - price, rent, ID etc. On the search box there are dropdown boxes with the search box. But it seems when I search something  it ignores the values of taxonomies totally and only search whats typed on the search box. See it here. http://tjdesigners.info/eshop/
 Please help me out I will be really grateful.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112376/how-to-make-cascading-drop-down-lists-using-mysql-and-php AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968095/server-side-cascading-dropdown-in-php ... try this examples and if you have some error, please post your relevant code